# Is opengl vsync fixed or it's can fluctuate?

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

In `OpenGl` (under android if it's matter) does `vsync` signal absolutely fixed at every 16.6 ms interval and can not fluctuate or could it be a little "moveable" in some circumstance ?

I mean it's must it be absolutely like this:

> 16.6ms --- 16.6ms --- 16.6ms --- etc

or could it be like this?:

> 16.6ms -- 18ms --- 16.6ms --- 15ms --- etc ...

I ask this because between each `eglswapBuffers` I have strange value like 15ms, 18ms, 22ms, etc... and I don't understand why.

this is the delay i have (in ms) between each eglswapbuffers durring an animation :

|10|13|16|24|17|10|17|17|17|16|17|19|15|17|17|18|16|16|17|17|17|17|17|17|17|17|17|18|16|16|17|17|17|18|16|15|17|17|17|27|20|20|15|14|14|17|10|11|17|17|20|19|14|14|17|17|17|44|27|13|18|14|16|17|21|17|11|17|17|17|17|17|17|17|17|18|15|17|17|18|16|17|17|17|17|17|17|16|21|12|17|17|16|18|20|18|13|15|21|14|21|24|24|20|7|7|14|17|17|17|17|17|17|17|18|21|24|19|21|16|10|10|12|16|17|17|18|16|17|17|16|17|17|17|18|19|18|12|15|16|17|17|17|23|13|16|23|13|14|16|17|17|18|16|19|15|21|17|13|16|17|17|17|17|18|24|18|11|11|26|19|19|12|17|14|8|14|17|17|17|

Comment: How are you measuring the value?

Comment: @Robinson with timer between each eglswapBuffers

Comment: What kind of timer?  Point is timer resolution may be > your constraint, i.e. it's not guaranteed to be correct.  That would account for the varying times.

Comment: I use clock_gettime if you know ...

Comment: Are you using CLOCK_MONOTONIC?

Comment: yes ... it's bad ?

Comment: No.   I'm just wondering about the accuracy on your platform.

Comment: Read the EGL specification if have not done so already. Also simply calling eglswapbuffers wont cut it. To make accurate measurements you need to put sync primitives (glFinish et al) before starting and finishing measurements, and take into consideration the driver may start or delay work whenever.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `eglSwapBuffers` doesn't actually swap the buffers; it's just an asynchronous signal telling the driver stack that the application has finished composing the current frame. The actual display swap may happen some time later, so the amount of time between swaps may well be a little variable, especially if you have other threads running which may add jitter to when the application thread is rescheduled.

Exact vsync performance depends on the display panel; it's normally 16.6ms (60 FPS), but YMMV, especially on desktop with technologies like g-sync (which is basically dynamically variable vsync).

Comment: yes, but if it asynchrone, why it's always wait around 16 ms? sometime more and sometime less ? because if it's asynchrone it's must return imediatly ? if it's really asynchrone how to detect that a frame was dropped ?

Comment: "how to detect that a frame was dropped" - you can't, it entirely depends on the display subsystem, which you'll have no visibility of.

Comment: my problem is that if eglswapBuffers is not regular, how can i make a smooth scrolling ? because i calculate every 16ms the new position of the scrolling, but if sometime eglswapBuffers take 22s, sometime 14s, etc, to return, then my scrolling will be not perfectly smooth anymore :( it's will look like something like 50 fps even if internally i don't have any frame drop :(